# Add unallocated free space to LVM

Tags: vmware, lvm

I added 5 GB to primary disk under VMware. I can see 5GB free :

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
    32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB            Free Space
 1      1049kB  256MB   255MB   primary   ext2         boot
        256MB   257MB   1048kB            Free Space
 2      257MB   215GB   214GB   extended
 5      257MB   215GB   214GB   logical                lvm
        215GB   220GB   5370MB            Free Space
```

How can I add this free space to my group volume ? I need create a new partition first?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a partition first and change partition's system id for LVM (code 8e).

Example:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb #Assuming this is the disk you added
press "n" #to create a new partition and following along.
press "t" #change the partition's system id to "8e"
press "w" #to write the changes

#Create PV.
pvcreate /dev/sdb1
#Add PV to the Volume Group
vgextend <VolumeGroup> /dev/sdb1
#Extend the logical volume
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/VolumeGroup/yourLV
```

Make sure the LV is not mounted when you extend it. Run "lvdisplay" to ensure the Logical Volume extended.

NOTE: If the filesystem doesn't expand you may try rebooting the machine or do fsck and then resize.